# cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to run my application on an android emulator. I made all the coniguration necessary but it always returns me this error. Thank you for your help.

Error info :

```
cordova.cmd build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\comit\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ (DEPRECATED)
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova
```

environment variable :

- ANDROID_HOME C:\Users\comit\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\
- ANDROID_SDK_HOME C:\Users\comit\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\
- JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\
  Path :

> 

- C:\Users\comit\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\
- C:\Users\comit\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\ C:\Program
- Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\

Emulator :

> Nexus_5X_API_25

Comment: Have you installed gradle in your system?

Comment: No but I find gradle name files in the folder ../platforms/android

Comment: just do a gradle -v and check what you are getting.

Comment: 'gradle' is not recognized as an internal command
or external, an executable program or a batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing Gradle in your system
as you are using a Windows system follow the following steps

**Step 1:-**
Download the latest version of Gradle from [here](https://gradle.org/releases).

**Step 2:-**
Unpack the Gradle distribution ZIP into C:\Gradle using an archiver tool of your choice.

**Step 3:-**
Under System Variables select Path, then click Edit. Add an entry for `C:\Gradle\gradle-6.0.1\bin`.

Create a new environment variable called GRADLE_HOME and add `C:\Gradle\gradle-6.0.1` value to it.

To verify Gradle installation execute `gradle -v`. It should return the gradle version.

Comment: But there is a .gradle file that already exists under this path

Comment: Index de C:\Users\comit\.gradle\
[parent directory]
Name Size Modification date
caches/  20/11/2019 16:50:42
daemon/  20/11/2019 16:50:06
native/  20/11/2019 16:50:00
workers/  20/11/2019 16:54:48
wrapper/  20/11/2019 16:46:54

Comment: existence of .gardle doesn't mean you have Gradle installed. follow the above steps and let me know what's happening.

Comment: it tells me that gradle is installed  C:\Users\comit>gradle -v

Welcome to Gradle 6.0.1!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Substantial improvements in dependency management, including
   - Publishing Gradle Module Metadata in addition to pom.xml
   - Advanced control of transitive versions
   - Support for optional features and dependencies
   - Rules to tweak published metadata
 - Support for Java 13
 - Faster incremental Java and Groovy compilation
 - New Zinc compiler for Scala

Comment: - VS2019 support
 - Support for Gradle Enterprise plugin 3.0

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/release-notes.html


------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.0.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-11-18 20:25:01 UTC
Revision:     fad121066a68c4701acd362daf4287a7c309a0f5

Kotlin:       1.3.50
Groovy:       2.5.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          1.8.0_231 (Oracle Corporation 25.231-b11)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

Comment: and also have you set GRADLE_HOME ?

Comment: Yes it's done  GRADLE_HOME = C:\Program Files\Gradle\gradle-6.0.1\

Comment: I will try to run the application on the emulator to see what it will give

Comment: After launching the emulator ("Nexus 5X API 25") and running the command "ionic cordova emulate android" it returns this error: [ERROR] "An error occurred while renning subprocess native-run"

Comment: put up complete stacktrace

Comment: I did not completely understand

Comment: do a npm i -g native-run